# Is it possible to get public static field from template class argument?

Tags: java

Given

```
class A {
   public static A newInstance(int x) { ... }
}
```

And several classes containing static fields of type `A`

```
class B1 {
   public static A MIN = A.newInstance(10);
}

class B2 {
   public static A MIN = A.newInstance(15);
}
```

I would like to parameterize a class with `B1` or `B2` to get `MIN` field of type `A` from class `B` in the class `C`:

```
class C <T, P> {
   private T t = ???;
}
```

When `C<A, B1> c = new C();` what should be placed instead `???` to get `B1.MIN`? 
Is it possible?

EDIT:
Thank you for the answers, I have upvoted both.
I have arrived simply at

```
class C <T, P> {
   private T t;

   public C(T min) {
      this.t = min;
   }
}
```

This will be just `C<A, B1> c = new C<A, B1>(B1.MIN);` because as you can see it is hard to avoid a constructor for `C` taking an instance of `B1` or smth like that. But in this case `B1` at least not instantiated.

Comment: Does `B.MIN` not work?

Comment: this sort of code will only work in c++. Java doesn't allow explicit template definition

Comment: @DizzyCode: There is no `B` in `class C <T, P>`

Comment: Generics handle the case when you *don't* know which class will be used. But in your case you know that you'll use `A` and  `B` - so use it! `class C { private A t = B.MIN; }`

Comment: *"Is it possible to get public static field from template class argument?"* I'm reasonably certain the answer to this question is "No." But not certain enough to put it out as an answer. :-)

Comment: @alfasin: I have several B-like classes with `MIN` fields and I hope there is a more lightweight method do get `MIN` instead of refactor and implement factory class. I tried several constructs like `(A)P.class.getField("MIN").get(null);` but that certainly did not compile :-)

Comment: I kind of follow question, except I do not see where class `A` comes in.

Comment: @weston: `A` is a kind of ValueObject pattern

Comment: @Antonio if you're trying to get the variable to match by its "name" and not by its "type" you're doing it wrong. Maybe you should explain better in the question what are you trying to achieve instead of what you are doing in order to achieve it. You might find a different (and better) approach. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @alfasin: I've extended the question

Comment: I'm confused. You want to grab a static field from a generic type  that you specified for `C`?

Comment: @vinceemigh: Yes. At least trying to do so...

Comment: @Antonio: If you only need to do this in a method that has received an argument of type `P`, then you can do the **really** ugly thing of `thePInstance.getClass().getField(...)`. :-) But you're better off changing the design...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I know that, but `P` should be instantiated for this. That might be ugly but I'm trying to find a quick temporary workaround

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface to achieve this behavior:

```
class A {
    public static A newInstance() { return new A(); }
}

interface HasMin {
    public static A MIN = null;
}

class B1 implements HasMin {
    public static A MIN = A.newInstance();
}

class B2 implements HasMin {
    public static A MIN = A.newInstance();
}

class C<T extends HasMin> { 
    private A t = T.MIN; 
}
```

Then you can create: `C<B1>` and `C<B2>` and use both.

As Tom suggested in the comments below, this approach is limited to use static fields. An even better approach would be:

```
public class Play {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B1 b1 = new B1();
        C<B1> c = new C<>(b1);
        System.out.println(c.getA());  // prints: A{ x=10 }

        B2 b2 = new B2();
        C<B2> c2 = new C<>(b2);
        System.out.println(c2.getA()); // prints: A{ x=20 }
    }
}

class A {
    private int x;

    public A(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A{ x=" + x + " }";
    }

    public static A newInstance(int x) {
        return new A(x);
    }
}

interface GetMin {
    public A getMin();
}

class B1 implements GetMin {
    public A MIN = A.newInstance(10);

    @Override
    public A getMin() {
        return MIN;
    }
}

class B2 implements GetMin {
    public A MIN = A.newInstance(20);

    @Override
    public A getMin() {
        return MIN;
    }
}

class C<T extends GetMin> {
    private A a = null;

    public C(T t) {
        a = t.getMin();
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `System.out.println(c.getMin());` instead :P. I guess the compiler replaces that method call with `A.s`, but it doesn't look like it using `javap -c xyz`. Strange, but I guess, it still doesn't help OP here, since he likes to pass a value to `A` and that field isn't `static`.

Answer (score 1):

I would forget static and have a concrete instance of an interface:

```
public interface Bounds<T> {
    T min();
}
```

The concrete instance could be singleton, so next best thing to a static:

```
public enum B implements Bounds<A> {
    INSTANCE;

    private final A min = A.newInstance(10);

    @Override
    public A min() {
        return min;
    }
}
```

`C` then defined like so:

```
public class C<T, P extends Bounds<T>> {

    private T min;

    public C(P bounds) {
        min = bounds.min();
    }

    public T getMin() {
        return min;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
C<A, B> c = new C(B.INSTANCE);
```

## Self describing

Maybe you don't want this meta data type (`B`), maybe you want types to describe themselves. So `C` could be defined for types that can describe their own bounds:

```
public class C<T extends Bounds<T>> {

    private T min;

    public C(T anyT) {
        min = anyT.min();
    }

    public T getMin() {
        return min;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
C<A> c = new C(A.zero); //any A will do
```

Where `A` is:

```
public class A implements Bounds<A>{
    public final static A zero = A.newInstance(0);

    private final static A min = A.newInstance(10);

    public static A newInstance(int x) {
        return new A(x);
    }

    private int x;

    public A(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public A min() {
        return min;
    }
}
```